# Find multiple regex matches in Java prohibiting non-matches

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a Java `Pattern` such as `\s+(foo|bar)` to find all the matches of `foo` or `bar` after whitespace. Using the matching group I can extract the actual matched text.

```java
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("\\s+(foo|bar)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(someText);
while(matcher.find()) {
  String value = matcher.group(1);
  ...
}
```

This works for strings like `foo foo bar` (note the preceding space), but it would also match things like `foo foo bad`. How could I either preclude the matcher from matching subsequent character runs that do not match, or detect that characters were skipped or there are no more characters remaining? In other words, I expect the entire string being matched to be a sequence of subsequent strings that match the pattern. How could I guarantee this?

The point here is to continue passing through the string finding matches. I could easily split the string and then perform additional comparisons, but I don't want the overhead of multiple regex passes, of array/list creations, etc.

Comment: What about `bad foo foo bar`?

Comment: @Nick, I would not want to match that, either, and I would want to know that there were characters that did not match.

Comment: Can you include some sample inputs along with what the exact output should be.  This is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix the regex with `\G`. Javadoc of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) says:

> `\G` - The end of the previous match

Of course, on the first match, "the end of the previous match" is the beginning of input.

This ensures that the regex matches will all be consecutive, starting at the beginning of the input. Doesn't mean the regex will get to the end of the input, you have to check for that yourself.

*Example*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("abc");
    test(" foo foo bar");
    test(" foo foo bad");
    test(" foo bad foo");
}
```

```
static void test(String input) {
    System.out.println("'" + input + "'");
    int lastEnd = 0;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\G\\s+(foo|bar)").matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("  g0='%s' (%d-%d), g1='%s' (%d-%d)%n",
                          m.group(), m.start(), m.end(),
                          m.group(1), m.start(1), m.end(1));
        lastEnd = m.end();
    }
    if (lastEnd == input.length())
        System.out.println("  OK");
    else
        System.out.println("  Incomplete: Last match ended at " + lastEnd);
}
```

*Output*

```
'abc'
  Incomplete: Last match ended at 0
' foo foo bar'
  g0=' foo' (0-4), g1='foo' (1-4)
  g0=' foo' (4-8), g1='foo' (5-8)
  g0=' bar' (8-12), g1='bar' (9-12)
  OK
' foo foo bad'
  g0=' foo' (0-4), g1='foo' (1-4)
  g0=' foo' (4-8), g1='foo' (5-8)
  Incomplete: Last match ended at 8
' foo bad foo'
  g0=' foo' (0-4), g1='foo' (1-4)
  Incomplete: Last match ended at 4
```

For comparison, without the `\G` in the regex, the output of that code would be:

```
'abc'
  Incomplete: Last match ended at 0
' foo foo bar'
  g0=' foo' (0-4), g1='foo' (1-4)
  g0=' foo' (4-8), g1='foo' (5-8)
  g0=' bar' (8-12), g1='bar' (9-12)
  OK
' foo foo bad'
  g0=' foo' (0-4), g1='foo' (1-4)
  g0=' foo' (4-8), g1='foo' (5-8)
  Incomplete: Last match ended at 8
' foo bad foo'
  g0=' foo' (0-4), g1='foo' (1-4)
  g0=' foo' (8-12), g1='foo' (9-12)
  OK
```

As you can see, the last example would have failed to detect that text `bad` wa skipped.

Comment: Andreas, this is awesome! This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for; thank you so much. One little caveat: the `\G` prevents embedding the pattern in a larger regular expression (e.g. `"test ((?:" + pattern + ")+)?"`), so if both are needed one would need to extract the pattern into two: a plain pattern for embedding, and the other prefixed with `\G` for iterative matching.

Comment: @GarretWilson ``\G`` is only for use when you make multiple matches, i.e. make multiple `find()` calls, because the "previous match" in the definition specifically refers to a previous invocation of `find()` *(or extended logic like `replaceAll(...)` and `results()`, which internally uses the equivalent of a `find()` loop)*. --- Your repeating pattern `(?:" + pattern + ")+` doesn't need ``\G``, since it doesn't allow anything between repeats anyway, and the entire regex is "one match".

Comment: @GarretWilson So if `pattern` is intended for either direct use or for embedding, then ``\G`` doesn't belong in `pattern`, it is the user of `pattern` that decides whether other characters before/between pattern match is allowed. E.g. for *not allowed*, `compile("\\G(?:" + pattern + ")")` and `compile("(?:" + pattern + ")+")` are equivalent, and for *allowed*, `compile(pattern)` and `compile("(?:(?s:.*?)(?:" + pattern + "))+")` are equivalent. *(The extra `(?:x)` are needed to guard against `pattern` using top-level `|`)*

Comment: Yes, I understand all that, and this is all fine. I was just pointing out this caveat in case someone tried to embed this form in another regex. In my library I easily created two separate regex patterns for these two separate use cases.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that requires doing an extra `match` is to first try to match the input against the following regex:

```
^(\s+(foo|bar))+$
```

Then you can do your repeated finds:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests =  {
            " foo foo bar",
            " foo foo x foo bar"
        };
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(\\s+(foo|bar))+");
        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("\\s+(foo|bar)");
        for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
            String test = tests[i];
            Matcher m1 = pattern1.matcher(test);
            if (m1.matches()) {
                System.out.println("Matches against: '" + test + "'");
                Matcher m2 = pattern2.matcher(test);
                while (m2.find()) {
                    System.out.println("\t'" + m2.group() + "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Matches against: ' foo foo bar'
        ' foo'
        ' foo'
        ' bar'
```

**If the entire input does not have to match, then we use a regex to find the prefix of the string that does:**

```
^(\s+(foo|bar))+
```

You can test the length of this match against the input to determine whether the entire string was matched.

And then:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests =  {
            " foo foo bar",
            " foo foo x foo bar"
        };
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("^(\\s+(foo|bar))+");
        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("\\s+(foo|bar)");
        for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
            String test = tests[i];
            Matcher m1 = pattern1.matcher(test);
            if (m1.find()) {
                String s = m1.group();
                System.out.println("Matches against: '" + s + "'");
                Matcher m2 = pattern2.matcher(s);
                while (m2.find()) {
                    System.out.println("\t'" + m2.group() + "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Matches against: ' foo foo bar'
        ' foo'
        ' foo'
        ' bar'
Matches against: ' foo foo'
        ' foo'
        ' foo'
```